# how to calculate and plot "precision recall curve" in MATLAB/Python for correlation based Object tracker?

Tags: image-processing, statistics, computer-vision, object-tracking

I have 2 text files. One contains ground truths while the other contains predicted bounding box values. I want to plot precision recall curve using the data of these two files. I shall be very thanksful to you if you could help me.

thanks

Comment: _you_ are expected to to the research. here, not related to tracking but to detection and localization... https://medium.com/@timothycarlen/understanding-the-map-evaluation-metric-for-object-detection-a07fe6962cf3 so it might get you on the right path -- oh, also, welcome :) please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: perhaps try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ -- you'll need to vary some parameter (detection threshold, threshold on "IoU" of tracker and ground truth), which will cause each result frame to be considered a true/false positive/negative, hence precision and recall.